# Signaling service for WebRTC

Tags: windows-10, uwp, webrtc, windows-10-universal

I am developing UWP (Windows 10) application and I need your recommendation for signaling service for using WebRTC and store user's data (-base).

Service which will be contains table of my users with default/custom fields and relations between them, and provide an opportunity to send messages/event for sending signals (call, ice candidates/answer etc) to interlocutor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write your own. It is really trivial.
Here is very basic example in Java (written by me): https://github.com/fycth/java-webrtc-signaling-server
Also, here is a bit more "feature-ness" example written in Erlang (I'm the author, again): https://github.com/fycth/WebRTCO/tree/master/apps/signaler
Signaling server is a relatively simple application, but it plays important role in the whole service. So, it is usually unreasonable to outsource signaling to some 3rd-party side.